# How to replace old version iOS app to new version available on AppStore forcefully

Tags: swift

This code return true if you are using old version and return false if you are using the latest version available on AppStore. If its return true than how should I replace old version app.

```
func appUpdateAvailable() -> Bool
{
    let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleIdentifier"]
    let identifier = bundleIdentifier as! String

   //  let storeInfoURL: String = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.xipetech.ecoTrak"

    let storeInfoURL: String = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)"


    var upgradeAvailable = false
    // Get the main bundle of the app so that we can determine the app's version number
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    if let infoDictionary = bundle.infoDictionary {
        // The URL for this app on the iTunes store uses the Apple ID for the  This never changes, so it is a constant
        let urlOnAppStore = NSURL(string: storeInfoURL)
        if let dataInJSON = NSData(contentsOf: urlOnAppStore! as URL) {
            // Try to deserialize the JSON that we got
            if let dict: NSDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataInJSON as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject] as NSDictionary? {
                if let results:NSArray = dict["results"] as? NSArray {
                    if let version = ((results[0] as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "version")!) as? String {
                        // Get the version number of the current version installed on device
                        if let currentVersion = infoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
                            // Check if they are the same. If not, an upgrade is available.
                            print("\(version)")
                            if version != currentVersion {
                                upgradeAvailable = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print(upgradeAvailable)
    return upgradeAvailable
}
```

Comment: you cant, you can only tell the user to update.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to tell user that an update is available through an alert! We cannot progrmatically update your version from appstore through app

I wouldn't recommend using this, but you can open appstore from app through an alert handler like this

```
refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/*******************")!) //Your appstore URL

                        }))
```

Comment: how can i open an alert in appdelegate??

Comment: You can show an alert in appDelegate but it will be shown in your initial view controller as appDelegate is not a viewController. Force-full updation may result in app rejection in app review by apple.

Comment: Thanks you Jeesson